# What is the difference between '[^ ]*' and '\S*'?

Tags: python, regex

When using regular expressions in Python, is there any difference between `'[^ ]*'` and `'\S*'`? Don't they both mean "match zero or more non-whitespace characters"?

Comment: tab/cr/lf and more are also considered whitespace by \s and \S whereas your character class only considers `" "` to match.

Comment: It is not hard to visit [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and check yourself. Pattern description on the right is usually quite comprehensive.